# Espresso: check if NavigationDrawer list item is selected

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-testing, android-espresso

I have an app with a `NavigationDrawer`. I want to test whether the right item is selected in the list of the NavigationDrawer using Espresso.

I found a way of clicking an item in the list view that works. I used the same approach to test whether or not the list item is selected. But the behavior is odd: for the first call it seems to work, but for the second call it doesn't. Any idea what could cause this, or how I could do it better?

I tried this:

```
// Open drawer.
openDrawer(DRAWER_LAYOUT_ID);

// We expect that the first item (map overview) is selected.
// Here it works fine. The check succeeds.
String mapOverviewTitle = mActivity.getString(R.string.map_overview);
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.title), hasSibling(withText(mapOverviewTitle))))
        .check(matches(isSelected()));

// Navigate to the login fragment. This works fine too.
openDrawer(DRAWER_LAYOUT_ID);
String loginTitle = mActivity.getString(R.string.login);
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.title), hasSibling(withText(loginTitle))))
        .perform(click());

// We expect that the login item is selected. 
openDrawer(DRAWER_LAYOUT_ID);
// This does not work. The check fails.
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.title), hasSibling(withText(loginTitle))))
        .check(matches(isSelected()));
closeDrawer(DRAWER_LAYOUT_ID);
```

The error message that I get from the second call is this:

```
android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'is selected' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: is selected
Got: "AppCompatTextView{id=2131558468, res-name=title, visibility=VISIBLE, width=240, height=48, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=72.0, y=8.0, text=Login, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to match isSelected() to a string rather than to a radio checkbox. Try changing the last step to onView(allOf(withId(R.id.checkbox_id), hasSibling(withText(loginTitle)))).check(matches(isSelected()));

Comment: Ok maybe I misunderstand the purpose of `isSelected()` completely. What I want to check is if a list item is selected, like the user tapped on it and then  the background color is different to signal the selection. There are no checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you will need to build a custom view matcher. You can look at the example here for the `inRoot()` method which will let you pick which window layer you are choosing to interact with. Your test is currently interacting with the textView on the topmost level, you want to interact with the layer one level before that and make sure your change has been initiated.

https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/source/browse/testapp_test/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/common/testing/ui/testapp/MultipleWindowTest.java

Comment: Could you elaborate what I need to do for the code I've posted? Not sure what you mean...

Answer (score 0):

Why not execute the code thru the `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position)` method like so:

```
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    Fragment frag = Dialer.newInstance("uselessParam1", "uselessParam2");
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            //code
            break;
        case 2:
            //code
            break;
        case 3:
            //code
            break;
    }
}
```

You just see which value matches up with the list item you want.

Comment: I want to use Espresso for testing, not add another callback method to my navigation drawer.

Comment: @Terry oh ok. I hope you find a solution in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I do it like this:

```
String fragmentTitle = mInstrumentation.getTargetContext().getString(TITLE_STRING_ID);
openDrawer(DRAWER_LAYOUT_ID);
onView(withText(fragmentTitle)).perform(click());
onView(withId(R.id.toolbar_title)).check(matches(withText(fragmentTitle)));
```

In case you have a toolbar with a textview toolbartitle inside you could check it like this.

Comment: This checks if the toolbar title matches the fragment title. This is not related to my question at all.

Comment: In my case when one is selected and you load the fragment, the title of the toolbar will change so it would be a workaround to know that is selected somehow